# Ranking non edges of graph based on score matrix

Tags: python, graph, networkx

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
G = nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([('1', '2'), ('1', '3'),('1','5'),('2','4')])
l= list(nx.non_edges(G))

score=np.array([[0.9,0.7,0.2,0.6,0.4],[0.7,0.9,0.6,0.8,0.3],[0.2,0.6,0.9,0.4,0.7],[0.6,0.8,0.4,0.9,0.3],[0.4,0.3,0.7,0.3,0.9]])
```

I want to rank the non edges based on the score matrix that is a non edge 1-4 has score 0.6 ,2-5 has score 0.3 so output will be [1-4,2-5]

edit-My actual data is in the form of a pandas dataframe(below is a toy dataset example of my actual dataset) which I am converting into a networkx graph object.

```
data1 = { 'node1': [1,1,1,2],
     'node2': [2,3,5,4],
     'weight': [1,1,1,1], }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['node1','node2','weight'])
```

the score matrix is in the form of a matrix 5X5 where the element score[1,4] represents the edge between the nodes 1 and 4 which has a score of 0.6

edit2-
From the graph 1 we can see that the missing edges are 1-4,2-3,2-5,3-4,3-5,3-5 and the respective score of them are 0.6 0.6 0.3 0.4 0.3 0.7 so we rank them according to the scores so the final output is 3-5 1-4 2-3 3-4 2-5 4-5

Comment: Some more information would be helpful: 1) Are you assuming that your graph will have 5 elements? 2) Do positions in your score array correspond to the adjacency matrix of the graph? 3) I don't see 0.5 anywhere in the score array -- how could that value be assigned to any edge (or non-edge)?

Comment: @apollo2020 see the above edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can find where edges are missing in the graph using nx.non_edges(), that function doesn't actually return objects that can be assigned data -- the non-edges don't exist in the logical graph, after all. However, you can create a second graph which contains all the edges not in the first graph, then assign your scores to the edges in the second graph.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np


G1 = nx.MultiGraph()
G1.add_edges_from([
    ('1', '2'),
    ('1', '3'),
    ('1', '5'),
    ('2', '4')])

G2 = nx.MultiGraph()
G2.add_edges_from(nx.non_edges(G1))

score = np.array([
    [0.9, 0.7, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4],
    [0.7, 0.9, 0.6, 0.8, 0.3],
    [0.2, 0.6, 0.9, 0.4, 0.7],
    [0.6, 0.8, 0.4, 0.9, 0.3],
    [0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.9]])

for u, v, d in G2.edges(data=True):
    i = int(u) - 1
    j = int(v) - 1
    d['score'] = score[i, j]
```

edit-

Now that I know you just care about the ranked edge vector and don't need to assign scores to the edges it can be done without invoking a second graph. You can use the built-in sorted() function and specify a lambda function for the key argument. The lambda looks up the score value for each edge and uses that value for sorting. Since you want the high-score edges first, you have to also specify reverse=True.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np


G = nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([
    ('1', '2'),
    ('1', '3'),
    ('1', '5'),
    ('2', '4')])

score = np.array([
    [0.9, 0.7, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4],
    [0.7, 0.9, 0.6, 0.8, 0.3],
    [0.2, 0.6, 0.9, 0.4, 0.7],
    [0.6, 0.8, 0.4, 0.9, 0.3],
    [0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.9]])

ranked_non_edges = sorted(
    nx.non_edges(G),
    key=lambda e: score[int(e[0])-1, int(e[1])-1],
    reverse=True)
```

Comment: which one is the output vector ?

Comment: Since you don't define a function or provide all of your code, I'm not sure what you mean by output in your example above. Can you explain why the output from your example above would be [1-4, 2-5]?

Comment: From the graph 1 we can see that the missing edges are 1-4,2-3,2-5,3-4,3-5,3-5 and the respective score of them are 0.6 0.6 0.3 0.4 0.3 0.7 so we rank them according to the scores so the final output is 3-5 1-4 2-3 3-4 2-5 4-5

Comment: I updated my answer above. Knowing that you just need the ranked edge vector but don't need to store scores in the graph makes it easier.